# Camera is not working on Android virtual device

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, android-camera

I am developing an Android base application with [PhoneGap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PhoneGap), and I want to use the camera to capture an image an store it. But when I launch the capture you have this image showing that the camera app has stopped unexceptedly.

Here is the screenshot:

https://plus.google.com/photos/113541644376045653443/albums/5735040545186264481/5735038652586673826

How do I fix this problem?

Comment: on the device or on the emulator?

Comment: You should send some code here.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure you add the camera support hardware feature.

Open the AVD Manager and edit your device.  Then under hardware click new and add camera support.

[image]

Comment: I've edited my avd preferences and the camera support is on "yes" but not working !

Comment: It would help to know what the error says in logcat.  I would also recommend deleting the device and creating a new one on a different api level.  Make sure you have all the latest sdk updates as well.

Comment: No one to help me ??? I am on ubuntu 11.10 ... It's a work i must give tomorrow !

Answer (score 0):

There may be problem in your function. Here I am posting a function. I hope it will work.

```
function capturePhoto()
{
    //alert("CapturePhoto");
    // Take a picture using the camera device and retrieve the image as a Base64-encoded string.
    navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess,
                                function(ex){alert("Camera Error!");},
                                { quality : 30,
                                  destinationType: destinationType.DATA_URL });
}
```